# I have imported a csv file from my desktop and I cannot import csv file to postgresql

Tags: postgresql, csv, import

Want to import this csv file to new table
[unicorn.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5gd8.png)

Created a Table "unicorns" through this syntax

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS unicorns (
company char,
url char,
last_valuation numeric,
date_joined char,
year_joined numeric,
city char,
country char,
industry char
);
```

Then I imported the file to 'unicorn' table but when I view the process, it displays no rows found.

I want to know the reason behind this problem so that I can address this in the future.

Comment: No way to answer this without detail on 1) The procedure for '...imported the file.."  2) What '... view the process...' means?

Comment: A CSV is text, so please use a text editor for copying the first few lines of it and pasting it in your question (instead of an image).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.